Is there a way to specify which prop is accessed on higher order components that have the same prop as a sub-component?
I am creating a higher order component in React to upload a file and display upload progress to the user.
I have a text component to display the file name and a progress bar component to show the progress. The props of these are the following:
interface TextProps {
  value?: string
  id?: string;
  className?: string;
  ...
}

type ProgressBarProps = {
  value?: number;    
  label?: string;
  isError?: boolean;
  ...
  };

A simplified view of how they are defined is below:
function ProgressBar({value, ...rest}: ProgressBarProps) {
  return (
    <DivWrapper>
      <Component {...(rest as T)} />
      <ProgressBar
        value={value}
      />
    </DivWrapper>
  );
};

function Text({value, ...rest}: TextProps){
  return (
    <Text value={value}>
    </Text>
  );
}


const TextWithProgressBar = ProgressBar(Text);

Now when I am trying to use this, I am doing the following:
function render(file) {
  const ProgressBarPropDef = {
    value: 50,
    isError: false,
    ...
  }    

  return (
    <TextWithProgressBar
      value={file.name}
      {...ProgressBarPropDef}
    >
    </TextWithProgressBar>
  )
}

When I remove {ProgressBarPropDef}, the file name in the text field is set correctly. But the {ProgressBarPropDef} overwrites the file name value when I include that line. I see that the same thing is passed in as value to both the Text and ProgressBar components. How can I pass a different value to both of these components?
I looked around and did not see anyone who ran into a similar issue. I'm assuming this is because it is bad practice to have conflicting prop names. However, these are shared components that I can't change the prop names of.
